# how to DONT add new attribute to default programatically

Tags: magento2

I have the following code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleSetup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;
    private $attributeSet;
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory; 
    } 

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        //creating attribute set 
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $data = [
            'attribute_set_name' => 'medicamento_expira_curta_FINAL', 
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
            'sort_order' => 200,
        ];
        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $attributeSet->save();
        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $attributeSet->save();

        $eavSetup->addAttributeGroup(
            $entityTypeId, 
            $attributeSet->getId(), 
            'medicamento_expira_curta_YYGroupFINAL', 
            200
        );

        //Creating products attributes
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                        'Data de NNFINAL',
                        [
                            'group' => 'medicamento_expira_curta_YYGroupFINAL',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'label' => 'Data de NNFINAL', //attr name
                            'backend' => '',
                            'input' => 'date',
                            'source' => '',
                            'required' => false,
                            'sort_order' => 5,
                            'default' => '0',
                            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                            'visible' => true,
                            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                            'visible_on_front' => true,
                            'attribute_set_id' => 'medicamento_expira_curta_FINAL',
                    ]
                );  

                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                        'Data de vencimento do YYFINAL',
                        [
                            'group' => 'medicamento_expira_curta_YYGroupFINAL',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'label' => 'Data de vencimento do YYFINAL', //attr name
                            'backend' => '',
                            'input' => 'date',
                            'source' => '',
                            'required' => false,
                            'sort_order' => 5,
                            'default' => '0',
                            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                            'visible' => true,
                            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                            'visible_on_front' => true,
                            'attribute_set_id' => 'medicamento_expira_curta_FINAL',
                    ]
                );  

        $setup->endSetup();


    }
}
?>
```

But, when i persist, the default attribute set receive this attribute too, but i need this not to happen. have a configuration for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code :

```
<?php


namespace Product\Attribute\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'data_de_nnfinal',
            [
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Data de NNFINAL',
                'input' => 'date',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => ,
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => null,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'system' => 1,
                'group' => 'medicamento_expira_curta_YYGroupFINAL',
                'option' => array('values' => array(""))
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'data_de_vencimento_do_yyfinal',
            [
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Data de vencimento do YYFINAL',
                'input' => 'date',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => ,
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => null,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'system' => 1,
                'group' => 'medicamento_expira_curta_FINAL',
                'option' => array('values' => array(""))
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: just replace above code and see it working

Comment: but i need to use only in specifict attribute set

Comment: you can add 
`'group' => 'medicamento_expira_curta_YYGroupFINAL',`

Comment: dont work, is in the default attribut set too, like my original code

Comment: i have updated my code you can add just your group name right

Comment: dont solve my problem, the group is in the default

Comment: i think your group name is wrong because above code is working for me and i have created extension for you

Comment: the attribute is assign to the correct group, but, when i create the group, it assigned to default automatically, i dont know why.

Comment: dont resolve my specific problem, but ill accept....

Comment: i have another problem, can u help ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257918/how-can-i-disable-hide-bundle-product-with-something-like-an-expir-date